# How to add package.Json file into our project in sublime text directory via command line?

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to create package.json( meta file) of my project, although  I have node.js+npm in my machine, but when I press npm init , then I don't know where the package.json file created, I want to create package.json file onto my project library in sublime text, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your terminal shell is in the correct directory.

```
$ cd ~/Documents/myProject
$ npm init
```

In order to create it in Sublime Text, you would need to search for some form of plugin or just save a file from called `package.json`.

The best thing to do is to run the commands, which there are packages for Sublime Text. There are quite a few in PackageControl, just search and take your favourite.